# Why do I get an auth error in TortoiseHG if I filter the traffic

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

My company just installed Blue Coat's Web Security Service and put the Unified Agent on all our computers.  It filters our HTTPS traffic w/ a CA that was added to all the computers.  We added the certificate to the `cacerts.pem` file.

We can no longer push/pull from our mercurial host (Kiln).  We get the message `abort: authorization failed`.  We have verified the credentials and verified that we can access the site from a web browser.  I have even tried doing a push with `--insecure` in case it was a certificate error.  What else can I do?

We have a mix of Windows 7 an Windows 8 computers.

```
Output of -v --debug

C:\Users\me\Documents\Development\Client Name>hg pull -v --debug https://mycompany.kilnhg.com/Code/Client/Group/New-Development
using https://mycompany.kilnhg.com/Code/Client/Group/New-Development
sending capabilities command
using auth.mycompany.kilnhg.com.* for authentication
mycompany.kilnhg.com certificate successfully verified
using auth.mycompany.kilnhg.com.* for authentication
http authorization required for https://mycompany.kilnhg.com/Code/Client/Group/New-Development
realm: kiln
http auth: user me@domain.com, password ************************
using auth.mycompany.kilnhg.com.* for authentication
mycompany.kilnhg.com certificate successfully verified
http auth: user me@domain.com, password ************************
using auth.mycompany.kilnhg.com.* for authentication
mycompany.kilnhg.com certificate successfully verified
http auth: user me@domain.com, password ************************
using auth.mycompany.kilnhg.com.* for authentication
mycompany.kilnhg.com certificate successfully verified
http auth: user me@domain.com, password ************************
using auth.mycompany.kilnhg.com.* for authentication
mycompany.kilnhg.com certificate successfully verified
http auth: user me@domain.com, password ************************
using auth.mycompany.kilnhg.com.* for authentication
mycompany.kilnhg.com certificate successfully verified
http auth: user me@domain.com, password ************************
using auth.mycompany.kilnhg.com.* for authentication
mycompany.kilnhg.com certificate successfully verified
abort: authorization failed
```

Comment: Show `push -v --debug` output